# Comparing strings in java android

Tags: java, android, string, string-comparison

How do I compare the String

```
http://192.168.74.1/sp/info.php?prodnum=0000000001
```

with

```
http://192.168.74.1
```

I only need to get the  `http://192.168.74.1` part of first string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to extract anything from the first string.  You can use [`String.startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29):

```
if (string1.startsWith(string2)) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1) you can use  `beginwith` function

```
String Mainstring= "http: // 192.168.74.1/sp/info.php?prodnum=0000000001";
if (Mainstring.startsWith("http: // 192.168.74.1"))
 {
 //Write your code here
 }
```

2) you can use `contains` function

```
boolean retval = Mainstring.contains(cs1);
```

retval will be `true` if it exist otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 3):

you can do

let

```
 str = "http://192.168.74.1/sp/info.php?prodnum=0000000001" 
then
if(str.contains("http://192.168.74.1/"))
{
//do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to check if the String Str starts with  another string try:

```
Str= "http: // 192.168.74.1/sp/info.php?prodnum=0000000001";

if (Str.startsWith("http: // 192.168.74.1"))
 {
 //do something here
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider you have String1 and String2.

To check if String1 starts with String2 , simply use `String1.startsWith(String2)` method

Here is the example:

```
String str = "abcd";
String newstr = "ab";

boolean flag = str.startsWith(newstr); // returns true
```

Please comment for further help.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(aString.contains("http://192.168.74.1")){
 //do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although checking .startsWith(...) is sufficient, since you want to match urls, it is better to parse the url and break it into components. This can be done manually, using regular expressions, but it is probably safer to use the java url parser. See [parsing a URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) for details.